# How to correctly trim user input in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have `TextInput` that receives `onChangeText` as a prop:

```
<TextInput
  ...
  value={this.state.myString}
  onChangeText={this.updateInput.bind(this)}
/>
```

And `updateInput` is represented as:

```
updateInput(newString) {
  this.setState({ myString: newString.trim() });
}
```

This works for Android only. Is there some way to trim user input on both platforms (iOS, Android)?

#### Update

Actually, string is processed as trimmed, but you can still type as many whitespaces as you want on iOS. And if you type two whitespaces in a row the dot appears like it would be the end of the sentence. This is undesirable behaviour, is there a way to avoid it?

Link with example video: https://streamable.com/dzl3c

Comment: why it wouldn't work on IOS?

Comment: I can't imagine. But I can type whitespaces freely on iOS. @slashsharp

Comment: Can you try to replace `trim()` with `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");`?

Comment: I've already tried such approach, unfortunately it doesn't help. Seems like it has something to do with with RN nitty-gritties. @PavelOganesyan

Comment: it only seems to work if you disallow spaces entirely, not sure if that works for what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: How could I disallow spaces? I'm passing `updateInput` as a callback, so it seems that key press will always be processed in the inner implementation of `TextInput` component. @RobbieMilejczak

Comment: you would have to do `.replace(/\s/g, '')` on the argument for `updateInput`. This leads to the user being able to input a single space at any given time, but that space will be removed after entering any other character. Honestly I would open this as an issue at the react-native github repo, this is not super important but it is weird behavior

Comment: Wise point, thank you @RobbieMilejczak

Answer (score 2):

One way to trim like this with `onChangeText` property with `value.trim()`. Here is a working example on my `RN 0.62.*`

```
 <TextInput
      name="email"
      type="text"
      keyboardType="email-address"
      keyboardAppearance="light"
      returnKeyType="next"
      onChangeText={value => { setValue('email', value.trim(), true) }}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.password.focus()}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={true}
      textContentType="emailAddress"
      editable={!isLoading}
      placeholder={Strings.INPUT_EMAIL_ADDRESS}
      placeholderTextColor={Theme.GRAY_LIGHT_COLOR}
      color={Theme.GRAY_DARK_COLOR}
      style={[styles.input, { borderColor: errors.email ? Theme.ORANGE_COLOR : Theme.PRIMARY_DARK_COLOR }]}
      ref={ref => this.email = ref} />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting form add trim() to that value.